# Can't set line spacing to '1' in Android Studio (anymore ?)

Tags: android, android-studio, editor

Not sure if it's related to a recent update, but I suddenly can't get single line spacing in the Android Studio Editor anymore. If I try to change it to 1, it let's me set it, but when I push 'Apply' it snaps back to 1.5.
Tried it with different fonts, but same thing.
Am I missing something obvious ?

[image]

Comment: so weird, it was persistent for weeks, my other devices were fine, then (I think) I had an update or something and now it works again, hmmm

Comment: Maybe this is also related https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207241829-Line-spacing-too-large-on-a-hidpi-display

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Were you able to resolve this issue? more info-- I am using high dpi resolution display and it seems to be still an issue

Comment: Same here. Is this already resolved?

Comment: Not sure if that's helpful, but I seem to be getting this when I move my laptop on/off a dock. Suddenly the fonts are all messed up (superlarge) and the line spacing is either kaput or suddenly I can set it to '1' again.

Answer (score 0):

[image: I can set spacing to 1, you have realy this problem???]

I can set spacing to 1, you have realy this problem???
Try again and tell me the result.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem in this way:**

- Open settings in Android Studio and go to Editor>Color&Fonts>Font. Now change the font or font size if you want and click on "Save As..." button and save the new scheme with a different name (In my case: Darcula E).
- If you are using Windows open File Explorer and navigate to Android studio's data folder and open config and then colors folder. In my case:
  `C:\Users\MyUserName\.AndroidStudio2.3\config\colors`
- Select and open the scheme that you created (In my case: `Darcula
  E.icls`) with Notepad. It looks like this:

```
`<scheme name="Darcula E" version="142" parent_scheme="Darcula">
  <metaInfo>
    <property name="created">2017-10-05T19:30:40</property>
    <property name="ide">AndroidStudio</property>
    <property name="ideVersion">2.3.3.0</property>
    <property name="modified">2017-10-05T19:30:50</property>
    <property name="originalScheme">Darcula</property>
  </metaInfo>
  <option name="LINE_SPACING" value="1.5" />
  <option name="EDITOR_FONT_SIZE" value="30" />
  <option name="CONSOLE_FONT_NAME" value="Monospaced" />
  <option name="CONSOLE_LINE_SPACING" value="1.0" />
  <option name="EDITOR_FONT_NAME" value="Source Code Pro" />
</scheme>`
```

Simply change `LINE_SPACING` value to "1.0".

- Now close and open Android Studio again. **Done!**

Comment: sounds like a very tedious WA, especially since it seems to come back (at least for me). It was ok for 6 month and now I have it again, argh ...